# Django Display User as user Full Name in Admin Field

Tags: django

I got stuck when trying to display User foreign as use full name

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.charfield(max_length=100)
  sales = models.foreignkey(User, on_delete=models.CASADE)
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Customer)
  list_display = ('name', 'sales')
```

nah by default sales as user foreign display as username. But i want display it to first name or full name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *Edited*

You can add a method in the ModelAdmin, as mentioned by @dirkgroten in the comments below:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    list_display = ('name', 'sales_first_name')
    def sales_first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.sales.first_name + obj.sales_last_name
```

The upside is you can handle null values as you wish, if your foreign key is not required, e.g.

```
def sales_first_name(self, obj):
    if obj.sales:
        return obj.sales.first_name
    else:
        return None # or return 'nobody'
```

### Old answer

(which, as mentioned in the comments, **does not work** (unless you use a plugin like [django-related-admin](https://pypi.org/project/django-related-admin/)))

Maybe use `sales__first_name` instead?

```
list_display = ('name', 'sales__first_name')
```

This way django will evaluate the first_name attribute of the user object instead of returning the default string representation (defined by the `__str__` method in the user model, which returns just the `username`).

Comment: Alternatively you can define any method in your ModelAdmin subclass to be a read_only_field that you can show in your list_display. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) for an example. So if you want to show the full name and it's not a field of `User` you can write a method (or use a property that is defined on `User` already).

Comment: @hundredrab getting error refers to 'sales__first_name', which is not a callable, an attribute of '___', or an attribute or method on '___'.

Comment: @FaturEwing, I've updated the answer. See if this works.

Comment: @hundredrab can i use it into frontend too? (template tag)

Comment: also in model.py ?

Comment: For using it in your templates you can simply use `{{ sales.first_name }} `? Not sure where or how you want to use it in models.py.

Comment: @hundredrab it works perfectly in template. I mean for the models.py i want show user field input in django admin dashboard show as first name too, by default it is username. How i implement it ?

Comment: when you say "_this_ does not work", what does _"this"_ refer to? `sales__first_name` or
```def sales_first_name(self, obj):

        return obj.sales.first_name + obj.sales_last_name```?

Comment: @DavidRhoden updated my answer to make it clear. The not-working part was `sales__first_name`.