# In Django, how do I access and display the full name of a user in an Admin filter, when the full name is a foreign key value?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-filters

I am using the default Django admin and User model. I'm trying to add a field to `list_filter` where the field's value is `username`. But I would like to display the user `first_name` and `last_name` in the filter. I'm not sure how to access those user values from the admin.

Here's a little code that doesn't work:

```
       list_filter = ('status', 'assignee_full_name')
       @property
       def assignee_full_name(self, obj):
         return obj.assignee.first_name + obj.assignee_last_name
```

(`assignee` is the field I'm sorting on, that's the one with the value that equals the username.)

This code as written doesn't work. The error message is
`<class 'intake.admin.ClientAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'assignee_first_name', which does not refer to a Field.`

What do I need to do differently to get `assignee.first_name` and `assignee_last_name` into a form that will be recognized or displayed by `list_filter`?

---

There's a similar question at [Django Display User as user Full Name in Admin Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264842/django-display-user-as-user-full-name-in-admin-field), in fact this code was derived from that answer, but the accepted answer is unsatisfactory; as it says right in the answer, it "doesn't work". I appreciate that the questions are substantially similar, but the answer provided does not answer the question.

Comment: Check if `obj.assignee` is a `User` object. That should help debug the problem.

Comment: I don't think I need to 'check'; it definitely corresponds to a User. The value of `assignee` is a username (or nothing). Are you referring to some other test I should do? Thanks for answering.